# Recommendation: Beginner needs to Regularly Post SQL Code for Troubleshooting. Where to?

Tags: discussion, sql-server

I am doing an internship that requires me to learn how to use SQL within SAS to run queries.  Since I have little experience, I will need to frequently post code in order to check it for efficiency as  well as bugs.  Is this a good place to do that, or is there a more appropriate resource you can think of?

Answer (score 3):

Please use [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), a Stack Exchange site dedicated specifically to, well, code review.

Comment: Great, thank you.

Comment: Code Review requires working code. If you are trying to debug non-working code issues, then you'll need to be sure that the code works first.

Comment: So, in line with my original question, can anyone suggest a resource where I can post non-working code?

Comment: I think there is a difference between "works" and "runs without error" - your code may have bugs, as in it has wrong/unintended results, but it still technically works, just not the way you expected. It can also be slow or, in your eyes, may be able to run faster. These scenarios are both ok for code review AFAIK. If your code actually doesn't work, meaning it returns an error instead of executing, then you should first search for the error message, then try to work out for yourself why it is returning an error; when you have exhausted those, that question is fine here.

Comment: No, code with bugs is not welcome on code review. http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options/3650#3650